# How to remove index from array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, indexing, key

Suppose I have such an array in php:

```
$ray =

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [0] => 1
            [ip] => 127.0.0.1
            [1] => 127.0.0.1
            [username] => local_me
            [2] => local_me
            [last_visit] => 2013-05-17 02:12:07
            [3] => 2013-05-17 02:12:07
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [0] => 2
            [ip] => 127.2.2.3
            [1] => 127.2.2.3
            [username] => Anonymous42
            [2] => Anonymous42
            [last_visit] => 2013-05-16 16:07:46
            [3] => 2013-05-16 16:07:46
        )

)
```

And I want to remove the `ip` (and '1' also) "column" for all elements of this array. How can I do this?

thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
foreach ($ray as &$item)
    unset($item['ip'],$item[1]);
```

Comment: @Mark Parnell, why did you use '&' at '&$item'?

Comment: To pass the item [by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php) so it updates the original array.

Answer (score 1):

This question was asked before here: [PHP Remove elements from associative array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450148/php-remove-key-from-associative-array)

It's really simple to remove a key from an array, just use **[unset](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php)** method.

```
foreach($ray as $key => $value){
   if(array_key_exists('id', $value){
      unset($ray[$key]['id'];
   }
   elseif(array_key_exists('1', $value){
      unset($ray[$key]['1'];
   }
}
```

Of course, there are few more options to do that more efficiently, I just try give an example.

Comment: Thanks ! But the definition of simple, for me, is "less lines of code", and I was trying to find (if exists) a function directly does that. Thanks for your effort, though !