# remove array key from php array

Tags: php, arrays

i have a array and want to remove its key values.. which are 0 ,1 and so on .. array have dynamic values.
and the key index can be dynamic increase or decease.

```
$url = Array 
        (
            0 => Array
            (
                'youtube ' => Array
                (
                    'youtube.com' => "https://www.youtube.com/dfssfskj8i"
                ),
            ),

            1 => Array
            (
                'youtube' => Array
                (
                    'youtube.com' => 'https://www.youtube.com/sfsfsd'
                ),
            )
        );



$temp = array();
foreach($url as $key => $val){
    foreach($val as $key1 => $val1){
        $temp[$key1][$val1] = $key1; 
    }
}
```

**I need Output**

```
Array 
    (

        'youtube ' => Array
        (
            'youtube.com' => "https://www.youtube.com/dfssfskj8i"

        ),

        'youtube' => Array
        (
            'youtube.com' => 'https://www.youtube.com/sfsfsd'
        ),
    );
```

Comment: You can't duplicate keys

Comment: You're not going to get exactly that output, since an array can't have the same key twice. Also, what's your problem/question?

Comment: And how would you distinguish between the two? What would $array['youtube'] be?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450148/php-remove-key-from-associative-array?

Comment: What's problem with original data, it will not take your thousands of GB space.

Comment: You can't get an array without a key. It's not an array then. Also, what does it matter to you if indexes are 0, 1 etc? Why do you *think* you need the output without those keys there?

Comment: try array_shift() in foreach

Comment: you can't duplicate array key and i think you want all values of youtyube in one array that you can achieve easily

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you're trying to do something like this:

```
$out = array();
foreach ($url as $key => $value){
    $dex = key($value);
    $out[$dex][] = reset($value[$dex]);
}
print_r($out);
```

If you get rid of the extra space after you key "youtube ", you'll get the following output:

```
Array
(
    [youtube] => Array
        (
            [0] => https://www.youtube.com/dfssfskj8i
            [1] => https://www.youtube.com/sfsfsd
        )

)
```

Comment: You could recursively call this chunk to get it to a 2Dimensional array?, also Array keys cannot be duplicated.. So only the last element with the duplicate key will be shown

Comment: @DarylGill - Is that more like what you were talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
$url = Array 
    (
        0 => Array
        (
            'youtube ' => Array
            (
                'youtube.com' => "https://www.youtube.com/dfssfskj8i"
            ),
        ),

        1 => Array
        (
            'youtube' => Array
            (
                'youtube.com' => 'https://www.youtube.com/sfsfsd'
            ),
        )
    );

$temp = array();
foreach($url as $key => $val){
  foreach($val as $key1 => $val1){
     $temp[$key1] = $val1; 
  }
}
```